# How can I get error message appearing in console to validation in UI in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I add [this error message in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5KtN.png) to my API Service validation? I can't get the logic on how I will add validation to my API Service if the user inputs an invalid event code. Hoping for your help. Thank you

**sample APIService code**

```
func validatePasscode(passcode: String, completionHandler: @escaping ((Event?, Error?) -> Void))
{
let passcodeURL = URL (string: "\(PASSCODE_CHECKER_URL)/\(passcode)")


Alamofire.request(passcodeURL!, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)

    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        if let passcodeJSON = response.result.value as? [[String : Any]],
            let passcodeObj = passcodeJSON.first {
            print(passcodeObj)
            let event = Event.init(JSON: passcodeObj);

            completionHandler(event, nil)


            }

    case .failure(let error):
        print("failure with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        completionHandler(nil, error)
        }

    }

}
```

**API Response**

```
SUCCESS: (
    {
    "closed_datetime" = "<null>";
    "closed_flag" = 0;
    "date_created" = "2018-07-12T12:53:00.000";
    "delete_flag" = 0;
    "deleted_datetime" = "<null>";
    "end_datetime" = "2018-07-13T13:00:00.000";
    "event_id" = "707024c4-8b93-46d6-b34d-e95b53b45750";
    "event_location" = "IT Room";
    "event_name" = "Laugh Trip";
    hasRaffle = 0;
    "participant_count" = 6;
    "registered_participants_count" = 5;
    "registration_req" = 0;
    "reopen_datetime" = "<null>";
    "reopen_flag" = 0;
    "start_datetime" = "2018-07-13T12:00:00.000";
  }
 )
```

Comment: Can you share complete response of your API? and one more thing use this wrapper class for Alamofire to reduce code: https://github.com/sohilmemon/AlamofireHelper

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Hi I added the Api response above. Thank you so much

Comment: @SohilR.Memon I checked it, seems good to use but I am bit confuse on how I will apply it. I am new in using swift.

Comment: It means either there will be a message in success block or [String:Any], Correct me if I am wrong. where is message in above API Response ?

Comment: @iOSGeek I haven't add the message in my code since I don't know how to construct the validation.

Comment: Can you just briefly tell what's your goal ?

Comment: Hi, the scenario will be, If I entered invalid passcode how will I construct the validation for that. My app keeps on just loading If I entered invalid passcode, and when I checked the console. It says "no event existing for the passcode ####". How will I get that message to reflect to the UI?

Answer (score 0):

If i'm reading this correctly, I think your `if let passcodeJSON = response.result.value as? [[String : Any]]` check might be failing.

I think it should be `if let passcodeJSON = response.result.value as? [String : Any]`, then you can access the values inside the dictionary using `if let message = passcodeJSON["message"] as? String`

```
 case .success:
        if let passcodeJSON = response.result.value as? [String : Any],
            let passcodeObj = passcodeJSON.first {
            print(passcodeObj)
            let event = Event.init(JSON: passcodeObj);

            // Can be used here
            if let message = passcodeJSON["message"] as? String {
                print(message)
            }

            completionHandler(event, nil)


            }
```

Comment: in which part would I insert `if let message = passcodeJSON["message"] as? String` ?

Comment: @Titus You can insert that after you've unwrapped `passcodeJSON`. I've updated the answer to show that

Comment: the message is just appearing in the console. How will I reflect the message as UIAlert to appear in my UI?

Comment: @Titus You would need to return the value in your closure. Then you wan use that value in a `UIAlertController`. You can read about it here https://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/